# Why is the middle segment of a 4 points cubic spline not matching a 100 points cubic spline?

Tags: interpolation, spline

Let's say I have `x0, x1, ..., x99` and `y0, y1, ..., y99`

```
X = (x0, ..., x99)
Y = (y0, ..., y99)

X_ = (x0, ..., x3)
Y_ = (y0, ..., y3)

S = CubicSpline(X, Y)
S_ = CubicSpline(X_, Y_)
```

I expect `S` and `S_` to be exactly match between `x1` and `x2`, but they are different in my code. I'm not here to ask coding questions. I just want to make sure are they supposed to be different?

My code uses scipy's CubicSpline function in the interpolation package, if you need to know which tool I'm using.

Comment: Why would you expect them to match? EG if you look at the matrix form, $y_4$ would likely impact the final answer.

Comment: @CalvinLin Because a third degree polynomial should be defined by 4 points.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the the cubic polynomial passes through all 4 points? EG Can you define how you're coming up with a cubic spline? Can you point to your reference that states $q_1(x_0) = y_0, q_1(x_1)=y_1, q_1(x_2) = y_2, q_1(x_3) = y_3)$ for the polynomial between $x_1, x_2$? $\quad$ FWIW Wikipedia / MathWorld states something that is very different, so I want to ensure that we're discussing the same technique.

Comment: I don't have the equation for that, but if you have used any cubic spline drawing tool, you know a cublic spline segment is defined by it's 2 ends and the control points of those two ends. When using cubic spline as interpolation, the control point of a point should be determined by its 2 neighbors. The control point of x1 should be determined by x0 and x2, the control point of x2 should be determined by x1 and x3. Therefore the segment between x1 and x2 should be determined by x0, x1, x2, x3.

Answer (score 0):

Between $x_0$ and $x_3$ there are 3 different cubic pieces (12 unknowns). If they join continuously up to the 2nd derivative that's 6 constraints, and the values $y_0,...,y_3$ adds 4 constraints. You need 2 more constraints for a unique solution, and usually they are chosen to minimize some measure of variation of the curve, which will be affected by any of the values.